# django-rest-framework: serializer from DATA don't update model ID

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've a simple serializer like this:

```
class CategoryCreationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
```

Category has an id field (Django primary key) and I don't get why the Serializer is not updating it.

Scenario: I've a BlogPost with a given category. I'm updating the BlogPost with a different Category (already created on the database). So the POST request will have all the BlogPost information with the new Category JSON object with the updated id:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "My first blog post",
    "category": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Techology"
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm doing this:

```
category_data = data.get('category')
    if category_data is not None:
        category_serializer = CategoryCreationSerializer(data=category_data)
        if category_serializer.is_valid():
            blog_post.category = category_serializer.object
```

inside category title will be updated but the id field will be NONE.
Can you explain me why?

Cheers, Emanuele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the official answer from the [issue I created](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2114) on django rest-framework git repository: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2114

> Short answer though is that by default ModelSerializer will generate a
>   read-only field for the id. (In the generic views you'll see that the
>   id is set explicitly by the view code, based on the id in the URL)
>   You'll want to explicitly declare the id field on the serializer so
>   that you can make it read-write.

So I managed to solve my problem leaving the Serializer like the one in my question ( without `id = serializers.IntegerField()` )

```
category_data = data.get('category', None)
if category_data is not None:
    category_serializer = CategoryCreationSerializer(blog_post.category, data=category_data)
    if category_serializer.is_valid():
        category_serializer.object.id = category_data.get("id", None)
        blog_post.category = category_serializer.object
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, the `id` field that is automatically generated by Django REST Framework [is read-only](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/650a91ac24cbd3e5b4ad5d7d7c6706fdf6160a78/rest_framework/serializers.py#L878-L879). Because of this, the `id` will always be none and it will try to create a new `Category` if there isn't already one attached.

You can override this by adding you own `id` field to the serializer that is not read-only.

```
class CategoryCreationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Category
```

Comment: This is a "special case" where Category will be None or an existing one. Something like the owner of the blog_post.

Comment: Now when I try to do blog_post.is_valid() it will fail with this error: "Category with this ID already exists."

Comment: @StErMi Try passing in the original `blog_post.category` as `instance` when you are initializing the serializer. This should put DRF into update mode instead of create mode, which appears to be what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to do that but it seems to not work, or at least is not working when the original blog_post.category is None (empty). I will update it with more info tomorrow when I have more time to test. Thanks.

Comment: here i got `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed`