# DRF3 M2M nested serializer removing nested 'id' fields on update()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a full-featured M2M (through table) nested serializer, which works perfect on create().  However, when I take the JSON returned by the GET version of serializer which contains the id's of the nested records and perform a PUT against the same serializer, the 'id' fields are removed from the nested record validated_data by the time it gets to the update() method.

```
{
"id": 1, 
"addresses": [
    {
        "id": 1,  # This is ripped out
        "city": "Oakville", 
        "addr": "13 Main St", 
        "postal_code": "01101"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2,  # This is ripped out
        "city": "Watertown", 
        "addr": "88 Main St", 
        "postal_code": "01101"
    }, 
    "customer_number": 1234, 
    "customer_type": 1, 
    "pricing_sequence": 2, 
    "name": "Customer number 1234"
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There's a duplicate of this somewhere, but the answer is that this is intended behavior for an AutoField.

Comment: Then given a nested M2M serializer there is no way to write an update method that updates the nested items because the update() method won't know the 'id' of the related record to update?  That makes PUT/PATCH worthless then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [django-rest-framework: serializer from DATA don't update model ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076918/django-rest-framework-serializer-from-data-dont-update-model-id)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is a duplicate of [django-rest-framework: serializer from DATA don't update model ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076918/django-rest-framework-serializer-from-data-dont-update-model-id)

I think I figured it out.  It seems the ModelSerializer by default makes the 'id' field read-only.  Solution is to add an explicit 'id' field to the serializer.  See tomchristie's comment https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2114